# GAWK script- Skip rows $6 OR $7 if = "" and STD calculation

Tags: csv, awk

I have put togheter in an awk script, the average and standard deviation from 2 columns (weight,height) and the % of olympic medals achieved (sum and group by male/female).

I only lack the std calculation as of right now.

Sometimes either the weight or the height fields have empty values. I would like to skip them if one of them is empty, to not affect the calculations.

$6=height,$7=weight

Header should be:

```
Country,Sex,Weight_avg,Weight_std,Height_avg,Height_std,% Medals
```

Imput data to test it:

```
id,name,nationality,sex,date_of_birth,height,weight,sport,gold,silver,bronze,info
736041664,A Jesus Garcia,ESP,male,1969-10-17,,64,athletics,1,0,0,
435962603,Aaron Brown,USA,male,1992-05-27,1.98,79,athletics,0,1,2,
266237702,Aaron Russell,USA,male,1993-06-04,2.05,98,volleyball,0,0,1,
87689776,Aauri Lorena Bokesa,ESP,female,1988-12-14,1.80,62,athletics,0,1,0,
997877719,Ababel Yeshaneh,ETH,female,1991-07-22,1.65,54,athletics,1,0,0,
343694681,Abadi Hadis,ETH,male,1997-11-06,1.70,63,athletics,0,4,0,
376068084,Abbey D'Agostino,USA,female,1992-05-25,1.61,49,athletics,0,0,1,
162792594,Abbey Weitzeil,USA,female,1996-12-03,1.78,68,aquatics,1,1,0,
803161695,Abdelaziz Merzougui,ESP,male,1991-08-30,1.75,,athletics,1,0,1,
```

The script is :

```
BEGIN { FS="," }
NR>1  { medals_all+= ($9 + $10 + $11)          # sum of ALL medals
        if ($3 != country) next                # if not the country of interest then go to next record
        found_country=1
        counts[$4]++                           # count of athletes by sex
        height_sum[$4]+= $6                    # sum of heights by sex
        weight_sum[$4]+= $7                    # sum of weights by sex
        medals_sum[$4]+= ($9 + $10 + $11)      # sum of medals by sex
      }
END   { if (found_country != 1) {
           printf "Sorry, country \"%s\" not found.\n", country
        }
        else {
           print "Country,Sex,Weight_avg,Weight_std,Height_avg,Height_std,% Medals"
           for (sex in counts)
               printf "%s,%s,%.4f Kg,%s,%.3f m,%s,%.4f%\n",
                      country,sex,
                      (counts[sex]>0) ? (weight_sum[sex]/counts[sex])    : 0,"weight_std",
                      (counts[sex]>0) ? (height_sum[sex]/counts[sex])    : 0,"height_std",
                      (medals_all >0) ? (medals_sum[sex]/medals_all*100) : 0
        }
      }
```

I was thinking of something like:

```
if ($6 | $7 = "" ) next
```

But it gives me an error and I don't know where to put it (After END block or before?)

Comment: Look into GNU datamash.

Comment: you can find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62844793/9510729) to calculate std, use `$4` for the hash key instead of `FNR,j` in that question and do weight and height in separate hashes.

Comment: The answer I posted shows you how to collect the input data in a way that lets you then trivial do whatever calculations you like with your data. If you need an algorithm to calculate std deviation you can always google for that or ask a new question if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Regarding `I don't fully understand if the avg and % calculation are ok` - what is it you don't understand about `avgWeight = ccWeight[sex] / ccMedals[sex]` and `pctMedals = ( ccMedals[sex] / (NR - 1) ) * 100`?

Comment: NR is a builtin awk variable that counts the number of lines of input read, you can't just try to use it as an array and hope to get some kind of result. You say you tried to use `ccMedals[Sex]` but in my code I use `ccMedals[sex]` (note the lower case `s` to match the variable I populate with `sex = $(f["sex"])` - is that the problem? I'm sorry but `is not giving back the good result` isn't enough information to try to debug whatever issue you're having.

Comment: You said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71960266/gawk-script-sum-group-by-avg-std-by-condition-calculation?noredirect=1#comment127343960_72070628) that my code only produces the header line, no data lines. Is that the problem you're trying to debug or not? Is that when you run it against the sample input you provided or against some other input?

Comment: Switch the order of what? OK, you;'re going to have to provide some more information on what it is that's failing and how it's failing (input, expected output, actual output, etc.) for us to be able to help you debug it.

Comment: this question already has answers; do not change the subject and body to address a new issue; rollback to the previous version of the question and then ask a new question for the new issue; to rollback ... at the bottom of the question, just to the left of your id/name, click on the 'edited XX mins ago' link, then scroll down to the previous version of the question and click the 'Rollback' option

Comment: @JoseAntonioPiedehierroArias `gawk -v country_code=USA -f tst.awk athletesv2.csv` is functionally identical to `gawk -f script3_4.awk -v country_code=USA athletesv2.csv`, there's no need to change the order of the `-f` and `-v` options (assuming `script3_4.awk` has the same content as `tst.awk`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `awk` idea (sans the code for std deviation)

```
$ cat athletes.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
NR>1  { medals_all+= ($9 + $10 + $11)          # sum of ALL medals
        if ($3 != country) next                # if not the country of interest then go to next record
        found_country=1
        counts[$4]++                           # count of athletes by sex
        height_sum[$4]+= $6                    # sum of heights by sex
        weight_sum[$4]+= $7                    # sum of weights by sex
        medals_sum[$4]+= ($9 + $10 + $11)      # sum of medals by sex
      }
END   { if (found_country != 1) {
           printf "Sorry, country \"%s\" not found.\n", country
        }
        else {
           print "Country,Sex,Weight_avg,Weight_std,Height_avg,Height_std,% Medals"
           for (sex in counts)
               printf "%s,%s,%.4f Kg,%s,%.3f m,%s,%.4f%\n",
                      country,sex,
                      (counts[sex]>0) ? (weight_sum[sex]/counts[sex])    : 0,"weight_std",
                      (counts[sex]>0) ? (height_sum[sex]/counts[sex])    : 0,"height_std",
                      (medals_all >0) ? (medals_sum[sex]/medals_all*100) : 0
        }
      }
```

Testing the script:

```
$ awk -v country=USA -f athletes.awk athletesv2.csv

Country,Sex,Weight_avg,Weight_std,Height_avg,Height_std,% Medals
USA,female,58.5000 Kg,weight_std,1.695 m,height_std,18.7500%
USA,male,88.5000 Kg,weight_std,2.015 m,height_std,25.0000%

$ awk -v country=ESP -f athletes.awk athletesv2.csv

Country,Sex,Weight_avg,Weight_std,Height_avg,Height_std,% Medals
ESP,female,62.0000 Kg,weight_std,1.800 m,height_std,6.2500%
ESP,male,65.5000 Kg,weight_std,1.735 m,height_std,18.7500%

$ awk -v country=ETH -f athletes.awk athletesv2.csv

Country,Sex,Weight_avg,Weight_std,Height_avg,Height_std,% Medals
ETH,male,63.0000 Kg,weight_std,1.700 m,height_std,25.0000%
ETH,female,54.0000 Kg,weight_std,1.650 m,height_std,6.2500%

$ awk -v country=XXX -f athletes.awk athletesv2.csv

Sorry, country "XXX" not found.
```

Comment: the `<test> ? <if_true> : <if_false>` construct is the [awk ternary operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Conditional-Exp.html)

Comment: basically, yes; to keep from generating a `divide by zero` error we're testing to make sure the denominator is >0; if the denominator is >0 then we do the calculation else (`:`) we generate a `0`

Comment: @JoseAntonioPiedehierroArias I had a couple typos in the original code; I've updated it in the last few minutes; make sure you've got the latest version; if you're still getting errors then please provide your awk version (`awk --version`) and an example of your command line call

Comment: awk version --> GNU Awk 5.0.1  I will check the updates

Comment: `GNU awk 5.0.1` should be sufficient

Comment: I deleted all of my files and then cut-n-pasted the `awk` script (`athletes.awk`) and your sample data (`athletesv2.csv`) into my environment, then ran the 4x sample test runs from this answer ... they all generate the same results as I've posted (in the answer); what is an example of your command line invocation?

Comment: The sample is short, I think some rows have empty values. Here you have the full file. https://github.com/jpiedehierroa/files/blob/main/athletesv2.txt    I will try just the input data in the meantime you try the full file. Perhaps is the empty values

Comment: I downloaded that file, ran my script for USA, and received: 
`Country,Sex,Weight_avg,Weight_std,Height_avg,Height_std,% Medals` / 
`USA,female,64.6601 Kg,weight_std,1.703 m,height_std,7.3580%` / 
`USA,male,81.1667 Kg,weight_std,1.837 m,height_std,5.6790%`

Comment: make sure the first line of `atheletes.awk` contains `BEGIN { FS="," }` (this defines the input field delimiter; without this the output will be limited to just the header); alternatively you could add `-F','` on the command line

Comment: keep in mind you'd be printing that message for *each* input line that does not match `country`; assuming you only want to print the message once then the general idea would be to add some code to the `END{...}` block, eg, did we find any entries for `country`? if 'no' then ... else ...; I've updated the answer with one idea

Comment: Ok, last thing! I discovered that even tough the calculation for the average is ok, the empty values in the full file is giving me slight deviations. Any way to replace these values from $6 and $7 with NA for example? Or in the whole file if it's easier?

Comment: without knowing what *slight deviation* looks like it's hard to know if there's a 'simple' fix or if we'll need a rewrite of the code; I'd suggest asking a new question that focuses solely on this *slight deviation* and how to process it; a few lines of input with a few columns should be sufficient ... show some columns with the *slight deviation* and some columns with 'normal' data; then explain what you want to do with the *slight deviation* ... ignore? set to a default value (`0`? `NA`?) once you have a solution to *slight deviation* then you can try modifying this answer as needed

Comment: Basically the counts variable takes into account these empty values, son for example when dividing by the total of counts, in one country I should have 188 and I'm dividing by 191, because of these 3 blank values. In one country is 3 empty spots, in another could be 0 or 5.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't attempt to do the std deviation calculation and idk how you're getting those medal percent numbers in your expected output but it should be easy for you to tweak this to finish off whatever it is you need to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = ","
    OFMT = "%.4f"
}
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        f[$i] = i
    }
    print "Country", "Sex", "Weight_avg", "Weight_std", "Height_avg", "Height_std", "% Medals"
    next
}
$(f["nationality"]) == country_code {
    sex = $(f["sex"])
    ccWeight[sex] += $(f["weight"])
    ccHeight[sex] += $(f["height"])
    ccMedals[sex] += ( $(f["gold"]) + $(f["silver"]) + $(f["bronze"]) )
}
END {
    for ( sex in ccWeight ) {
        avgWeight = ccWeight[sex] / ccMedals[sex]
        stdWeight = "foo"
        avgHeight = ccWeight[sex] / ccMedals[sex]
        stdHeight = "bar"
        pctMedals = ( ccMedals[sex] / (NR - 1) ) * 100

        print country_code, sex, avgWeight, stdWeight, avgHeight, stdHeight, pctMedals
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -v country_code=USA -f tst.awk athletesv2.csv
Country,Sex,Weight_avg,Weight_std,Height_avg,Height_std,% Medals
USA,female,39,foo,39,bar,33.3333
USA,male,44.2500,foo,44.2500,bar,44.4444
```

```
$ awk -v country_code=ESP -f tst.awk athletesv2.csv
Country,Sex,Weight_avg,Weight_std,Height_avg,Height_std,% Medals
ESP,female,62,foo,62,bar,11.1111
ESP,male,43.6667,foo,43.6667,bar,33.3333
```

```
$ awk -v country_code=ETH -f tst.awk athletesv2.csv
Country,Sex,Weight_avg,Weight_std,Height_avg,Height_std,% Medals
ETH,male,15.7500,foo,15.7500,bar,44.4444
ETH,female,54,foo,54,bar,11.1111
```

Here's another possible interpretation of how to calculate average medals given your comment below but it still doesn't produce the output you want so I guess you mean something different again:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = ","
    OFMT = "%.4f"
}
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        f[$i] = i
    }
    print "Country", "Sex", "Weight_avg", "Weight_std", "Height_avg", "Height_std", "% Medals"
    next
}
{
    sex = $(f["sex"])
    numMedals = ( $(f["gold"]) + $(f["silver"]) + $(f["bronze"]) )
    allMedals[sex] += numMedals
}
$(f["nationality"]) == country_code {
    ccWeight[sex] += $(f["weight"])
    ccHeight[sex] += $(f["height"])
    ccMedals[sex] += numMedals
}
END {
    for ( sex in ccWeight ) {
        avgWeight = ccWeight[sex] / ccMedals[sex]
        stdWeight = "foo"
        avgHeight = ccWeight[sex] / ccMedals[sex]
        stdHeight = "bar"
        pctMedals = ( ccMedals[sex] / allMedals[sex] ) * 100

        print country_code, sex, avgWeight, stdWeight, avgHeight, stdHeight, pctMedals
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -v country_code=USA -f tst.awk athletesv2.csv
Country,Sex,Weight_avg,Weight_std,Height_avg,Height_std,% Medals
USA,female,39,foo,39,bar,60
USA,male,44.2500,foo,44.2500,bar,36.3636
```

Comment: OK, there's a couple of different possible interpretations of that statement but, whatever it is you need, it's an easy tweak. I added a second script implementing what I thought you meant but apparently I still don't understand what the average is supposed to be.

Comment: Then either you copy/pasted the script wrong or your real data doesn't look like the sample you provided.

Comment: `cat tst.awk` is showing you the content of a file named `tst.awk` and that content is an awk script. `awk -f tst.awk` is calling awk and telling it to exceute (actually interpret) that awk script. The CSV file is named `athletesv2.csv`. See the awk man page for how to call awk but you're doing **exactly** the same thing as I'm doing with `awk -v country_code=USA -f tst.awk athletesv2.csv` in your question with `gawk -f script3_4.awk -v country_code=USA athletesv2.csv` so idk why you're asking what my call to awk is doing when it's functionally identical to yours.

Answer (score -1):

A single unified solution that no longer requires the user to manually enter nations one at a time :

- the `PROCINFO[ ]` bit is for swapping from `mawk` to `gawk`
  while retaining some semblance of sorted order

==

```
< test_athletesv2.csv\
\
| WHINY_USERS=1 mawk '
  function sum(_,__,___) { 
      if(+__<-__) { 
           return sprintf(OFMT,$_) 
      }
      ___=""
      for(_;_<=__;_+=3) {
         ___+=$_ }
      return +___ 
   } 
   function mean(_,__) {
       return \
          sprintf(OFMT,
          (+__<-__ ? +$_ :2/__*sum(_,__))\
                          /(100.0^(_==1)))
   }
   function sd(_,__,___,____,_____) {
       if(+__<-__) {
           return "0.0000000"
       }
       ____=""
       _____=100^(_==1)
       for(_;_<=+__;_+=3) {
           ____+=(($_)/_____-___)^2
       }
       return (____/(__/(_=2)))^_--^-_ 
  }
  function printreport(_,__,___) {
      ___=""
      print substr(_,__~__,index(_,"=")-1),
            substr(_,      index(_,"=")+(_=1)),
            ___=mean(_,__),sd(_++,__,___),
            ___=mean(_,__),sd(_++,__,___),
            sprintf("%8.4f-%%",sum(_,__)*100/_______)  
 } 
 BEGIN {  _ = ""
 PROCINFO[    "sorted_in"  \
          ] = "@ind_str_asc";
        ___ = 3
     ______ = " Country,Gender,Weight_avg,Weight_std"\
              ",Height_avg,Height_std,%-Medals"
     SUBSEP =   "="
        OFS = FS = ","
       
 getline } { sub("$",sprintf("=%.f=%.f=%.f", \
                             int(100*$6),$7,-_\
                             +(_+=+$9+$10+$11)),
                      _____[____[$___]=$___,$4]) 
 } END {
      _______ = +_
          ___ =  3
           FS = SUBSEP
      CONVFMT = OFMT ="%13.7f"
 
      for(_ in ____) {
          printf("%s%s%s",ORS,______,ORS)
          for(__ in _____) {
              if(index(__,_)) {
                  $+FS=substr(_____[__],—-___)
                  printreport(__,(-!!___)^(NF==++___)*NF) 
              } 
          }
      }
 }' | column -s',' -t | column -t |   lgp3 3 

Country  Gender  Weight_avg  Weight_std  Height_avg  Height_std  %-Medals
ESP      female  1.8000000   0.0000000   62.0000000  0.0000000   6.2500-%
ESP      male    1.1566667   0.4723660   43.6666667  17.8688639  18.7500-%

Country  Gender  Weight_avg  Weight_std  Height_avg  Height_std  %-Medals
ETH      female  1.6500000   0.0000000   54.0000000  0.0000000   6.2500-%
ETH      male    1.7000000   0.0000000   63.0000000  0.0000000   25.0000-%

Country  Gender  Weight_avg  Weight_std  Height_avg  Height_std  %-Medals
USA      female  1.1300000   0.4665119   39.0000000  17.7106371  18.7500-%
USA      male    1.3400000   0.5476008   59.0000000  25.3048085  25.0000-%
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I was asking. Thanks for the effort but I need the output to be based on a parameter (country), so manual entry needed. Thanks anyway

Comment: Then just filter out by country AFTERWARDS - take the 3 rows you need among them, e.g. pipe that output and do " grep -B 1 -F 'USA,' " (it doesn't have commas now only cuz i ran it past "column". Remove that bit and u have ur original format request.

Comment: @Jose : all stats, except medal counts, are within each nation and gender band, the same as what u wanted. what u asked for is a subset of this output. i only used column -t to make the output nicer to look at here instead of being a CSV